# Using AJAX to search, sort, and paginate in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, railscasts

I'm trying to do a real-time search in a **Rails 4.0.1** application.
I used the [Railscasts #240 tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax?view=asciicast), but I am not getting the same results as the cast. It seems that my only issue is with the AJAX script, but I don't know why or how.

**`app/views/subproducts/index.html.erb`**

```
<%= form_tag subproducts_path, :method => 'get', :id => "subproducts_search" do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
  <div id='subproducts'>
    <%= render 'subproducts' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

---

**`app/views/index.js.erb`**

```
$('#subproducts').html('<%= escape_javascript(render("subproducts")) %>');
```

---

**`app/views/_subproducts.html.erb`**

```
<table class="table table-stripped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><Center>Nombre</Center></th>
      <th><Center>Codigo</Center></th>
      <th><Center>Marca</Center></th>
      <th><Center>Categoria</Center></th>
      <th><Center>Precio De Compra</Center></th>
      <th><Center>Precio De Venta</Center></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% for subproduct in @subproducts%>
      <tr>
        <td><CENTER><%= subproduct.name %></CENTER></td>
        <td><CENTER><%= subproduct.code %></CENTER></td>
        <td><CENTER><%= subproduct.product.brand %></CENTER></td>
        <td><CENTER><%= subproduct.product.category %></CENTER></td>
        <td><CENTER><%= subproduct.product.bought_price %></CENTER></td>
        <td><CENTER><%= subproduct.product.sale_price %></CENTER></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<%= will_paginate @subproducts %>
```

---

**`app/models/subproduct.rb`**

```
class Subproduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :sale
  attr_accessible :code, :sale_id, :available, :name

  def cancelar_venta
    self.available = true
    self.sale_id = nil               
  end

  before_create do
    self.available = true
  end

  def self.search(search)
    if search
      where('code LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
    else
      Subproduct.all
    end
  end
end
```

---

**`app/controllers/subproducts_controller.rb`**

```
class SubproductsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @subproduct = @product.subproducts.create(params[:subproduct].permit(:code, :name))
    redirect_to product_path(@product)
  end

  def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @subproduct = @product.subproducts.find(params[:id])
    @subproduct.destroy
    redirect_to product_path(@product)        
  end

  def index
    # @subproducts = Subproduct.all
    @subproducts = Subproduct.search(params[:search]).paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])     
  end

  def agregar_subproducto_venta
    @subproduct = Subproduct.find(params[:id])
    @subproduct.sale_id = params[:sale_id]
    @subproduct.available = false
    @subproduct.save
    @sale = Sale.find(params[:sale_id])
    @sale.price = @sale.price + @subproduct.product.sale_price  
    @sale.save
    redirect_to sale_path(@sale)
  end

  def eliminar_subproducto_venta
    @subproduct = Subproduct.find(params[:id])
    @subproduct.sale_id = nil
    @subproduct.available = true  
    @subproduct.save
    @sale = Sale.find(params[:sale_id])
    @sale.price = @sale.price - @subproduct.product.sale_price  
    @sale.save
    redirect_to sale_path(@sale)
  end
end
```

---

**`public/javascripts/application.js`**

```
$(function () {
  // pagination links
  $('#subproducts .pagination a').live('click', function () {
     $.getScript(this.href);
     return false;
  });
  // Search form
  $('#subproducts_search input').keyup(function () {
    $.get($('#subproducts_search').attr('action'), &crarr;      
    $('#subproducts_search').serialize(), null, 'script');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @Oscar_sgc I am facing the same issue, but instead of HTML I am using HAML. There is no error showing in my log file which means that my "show_workers.js.haml" file is not responding. Below is the code of that file
`$("#workers").html("#{escape_javascript(render("workers"))}");`

If you had found the solution then please let me know, as I have followed the same episode and at the end searching and sorting is not working via AJAX, but working perfectly fine without AJAX

Comment: @Arif I myself am looking for a new tutorial, because this Railscast is far too old to use anymore. The AJAX/JS part is from over 5 years ago, with some methods deprecated. And I do not suggest downgrading your gems!

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what error you are getting so its hard to tell. But from the looks of things  it is your `app/views/index.js.erb file`. When rails responds with javascript it can not find the index.js file.

The folder path should include the class name. Thus, your "app/views/index.js.erb file" name  should be

```
app/views/subproducts/index.js.erb
```

note the addition of subproducts.

In the event that does not work you can also try out the following:

1) You can use remote true with your form_for and then skip on writing the p        ublic/javascripts/application.js file

2) Add remote true to your form_tag (i.e)

```
<%= form_tag('/articles', remote: true) do %> 
 ...
<% end %>
```

you can find more information on remote true and rails ajax calls here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

3) In your controller you should have the following

```
def index 
 @subproducts = Subproduct.search(params[:search]).paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])   
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html 
   format.js
 end 
end
```

4) in app/views/subproducts/index.js.erb file add your code

```
$('#subproducts').html('<%= escape_javascript(render("subproducts")) %>');
```

Hopefully one of those two options works for you.