# How to change Js code to Coffee code

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

i have this JS code:

```
$('#subproducts_search input').keyup(function () {
    $.get($('#subproducts_search').attr('action');      
    $('#subproducts_search').serialize(), null, 'script');
    return false;
  });
```

and i changed it for this:

```
$('#products_search input').keyup(()->
  $.get($('#products_search').attr('action')   
  $('#products_search').serialize(), null, 'script'))
  return false
```

but i get:

> SyntaxError: [stdin]:9:1: unexpected indentation

someone can help me? thanks

Comment: @Amadan im sorry i already updated the question my friend

Comment: Your first code block is invalid.

Comment: @squint i tried with this tutorial my friend i got the code from there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838777/using-ajax-to-search-sort-and-paginate-in-rails-4

Comment: The problem is not with your coffeescript, the javascript you are starting with is wrong as commented above. Anyway to convert JavaScript to CoffeeScript and vice versa there's a great online tool http://js2.coffee/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bracketing was wrong.

```
$('#products_search input').keyup(()->
  $.get($('#products_search').attr('action')   
  $('#products_search').serialize(), null, 'script')
  return false)
```

However, I'd probably write it so, without brackets to get confused about:

```
$('#products_search input').keyup () ->
  $.get $('#products_search').attr('action'),
        $('#products_search').serialize(), null, 'script'
  false
```

Comment: thanks a lot my friend!! works fine!!! <3!! where do i send you the beers? hehe :D

Answer (score 0):

There's a site designed to do just that. [js2.coffee](http://js2.coffee/) You write your javascript and it transforms it on the spot.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15950691)

Comment: I did not need to critique or receive clarification from the author. They specifically asked "How to change Js code to Coffee code" and I provided a method of doing so.